# Is a deviation from the equal flavor ratio of neutrinos ruled out experimentally?

Tags: astronomy, neutrinos, particle-detectors

Neutrinos have a lifetime which exceeds the lifetime of our universe. Therefore we measure an equal ratio of all three neutrino flavors, 1:1:1. However, lets assume that the heavier neutrinos can decay into the lightest neutrino very fast, so that only the lightest neutrino is measured in detectors. Then we had a distinct ratio of neutrino flavors measured, deviating from 1:1:1. Is such a theoretical scenario ruled out experimentally?

Comment: *"Therefore we measure an equal ratio of all three neutrino flavors, 1:1:1."* Er ... in what context do you suggest that we measure this? In the experimental contexts that I'm aware of there is only one source that we measure that way and it is not at all clear that the relic neutrinos should be so just from their temperature.